# How to disable logging in easy localization package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-easy-localization

I'm using easy localization package in my flutter app and the logger keeps firing Localization key not found !.

It's annoying and i can't trace anything in my terminal, How can i disable it ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For disable logger, change Build Modes in [Easy Logger] to empty List [link](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization#-logger)

```
EasyLocalization.logger.enableBuildModes = [];
```